# Tensorflow: How to read MNIST CSV file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to read a CSV file where one row looks like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

It's the MNIST dataset where a 784-bit row gives the pixels for a 28x28 image and a 0 is an uncoloured pixel and a 1 is a coloured pixel. Now, here's my attempt to read this data:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["binMNIST_data/bindigit_trn.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, row = reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [0]*784

records = tf.decode_csv(row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack(records)
```

This produces an error which I don't know what to do about:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    685           graph_def_version, node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors,
--> 686           input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
    687   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    472             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 473             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    474     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'DecodeCSV_4' (op: 'DecodeCSV') with input shapes: [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0d89c0bcf3a4> in <module>()
      8 record_defaults = [0]*784
      9 
---> 10 records = tf.decode_csv(row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
     11 features = tf.stack(records)

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py in decode_csv(records, record_defaults, field_delim, use_quote_delim, name, na_value)
   1204       records=records, record_defaults=record_defaults,
   1205       field_delim=field_delim, use_quote_delim=use_quote_delim,
-> 1206       na_value=na_value, name=name)
   1207   # pylint: enable=protected-access

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py in _decode_csv(records, record_defaults, field_delim, use_quote_delim, na_value, name)
     64         "DecodeCSV", records=records, record_defaults=record_defaults,
     65         field_delim=field_delim, use_quote_delim=use_quote_delim,
---> 66         na_value=na_value, name=name)
     67     _result = _op.outputs[:]
     68     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    785         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    786                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 787                          op_def=op_def)
    788       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    789 

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   3160         op_def=op_def)
   3161     self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_shapes=compute_shapes,
-> 3162                            compute_device=compute_device)
   3163     return ret
   3164 

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_op_helper(self, op, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   3206     # compute_shapes argument.
   3207     if op._c_op or compute_shapes:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 3208       set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   3209     # TODO(b/XXXX): move to Operation.__init__ once _USE_C_API flag is removed.
   3210     self._add_op(op)

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   2425     return _set_shapes_for_outputs_c_api(op)
   2426   else:
-> 2427     return _set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   2428 
   2429 

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   2398       shape_func = _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op
   2399 
-> 2400   shapes = shape_func(op)
   2401   if shapes is None:
   2402     raise RuntimeError(

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in call_with_requiring(op)
   2328 
   2329   def call_with_requiring(op):
-> 2330     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
   2331 
   2332   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op = call_with_requiring

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn)
    625     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
    626                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
--> 627                                   require_shape_fn)
    628     if not isinstance(res, dict):
    629       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).

~/Documents/Programming/ANN/labs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    689       missing_shape_fn = True
    690     else:
--> 691       raise ValueError(err.message)
    692 
    693   if missing_shape_fn:

ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'DecodeCSV_4' (op: 'DecodeCSV') with input shapes: [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [].
```

What is the problem here?